# Showing publishing pages in page viewer webpart

Tags: 2013, web-part

We have a pages library of several different article pages. I want to "embed" those pages into another area of our SP site.

I was thinking to use the Page Viewer webpart (or to make my own iframe). Either way, I get the whole page including the suite bar and current navigation sidepanel. But this is confusing to the user because there are two different suitebars and navigation schemes. Also I don't want them navigating inside the iframe.

Basically I want the content in **DeltaPlaceHolderMain**. And I can probably use jQuery to extract that and reparent it where I want. Is that the best approach? Is there some other more "SharePointy" way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the query string parameter to the URL: `IsDlg=1`

Can't test right now but that works for dialogs. Maybe it works for the page viewer too. I can try it out when I get back to my desk.

**EDIT**
Thanks to [Akhoy](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/13799/akhoy) for pointing out an issue with `IsDlg` when using the PageViewer web part.

[David Lozzi's blog](http://davidlozzi.com/2014/03/25/we-all-know-what-sharepoint-isdlg-does-wait-what-the/) describes the issue but basically, use `IsDlg` if viewing the page in a SharePoint dialog. If viewing in a page viewer web part, use lowercase `isdlg`.

> ...if you send the page `IsDlg`, SharePoint forces the size of the window and disables the scrolling. If you send `isdlg`, SharePoint does nothing with it except for hiding the CSS elements (as we discussed earlier). Your browser’s native capabilities kick in and scrolling occurs.
>
> This is great for the dialog interface SharePoint is use to as they will size with the page. Now the user is scrolling the entire page and not just the page within the dialog. This is annoying for us if we want to use `IsDlg` feature elsewhere and we want to scroll just inside the web part. We have to use the `isdlg` option instead.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to do the trick. Where did you find that? Are there other useful things like that. In the past I found this resource http://blogs.msdn.com/b/how24/archive/2013/05/23/famous-sharepoint-urls-amp-locations.aspx. It did include that parameter, but I didn't know what "Dialog view" meant. Awesome.

Comment: There is a catch with IsDlg. See : http://davidlozzi.com/2014/03/25/we-all-know-what-sharepoint-isdlg-does-wait-what-the/

Comment: Nice catch Akhoy. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Very interesting Akhoy. I've always used the parameter in SharePoint dialogs so haven't noticed it.

Comment: @Rothrock, I learnt about this paramter when styling some custom dialogs. I got tired of launching the dialog all the time.